# How to write shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am new to Linux commands. I have a requirement where I want to start Tomcat using a shell script. The location of `startup.sh` file is in `/usr/lib/apache-tomcat-7.0.14/bin/`. Tomcat is starting using command `sh startup.sh`. I want to create a shell script so that it will go to that folder and will execute `sh startup.sh` command. How can I do this using a shell script? Can anyone share the script for doing this?

Comment: What would you type at the command line?  Type it into a file instead, and then make the file executable. Alternatively, if you have `$HOME/bin` on your PATH, you could create a symlink to the file: `ln -s /usr/lib/apache-tomcat-7.0.14/bin/startup.sh ~/bin/tomcat` or some other name of your choosing.

Comment: Read [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) and learn how to use an editor (`emacs` or `gedit` or `gvim`, etc...) ... You probably would need to `chmod a+rx` your shell script, and learn what `PATH` is used for.

Answer (score 2):

Are you serious?

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /usr/lib/apache-tomcat-7.0.14/bin/
sh startup.sh
```

Comment: how to execute this script

Comment: The same way you execute any script?  What are you asking?

Comment: i am new to shell scripting.So what i understood is i need to create .sh file and need to copy commands that u provided.then i need to execte that file.am i correct??

Comment: if i want to execte same script for a remote machine,then what change i need to make

Comment: Maybe you should go back to basics on this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

exec /usr/lib/apache-tomcat-7.0.14/bin/startup.sh
```

is simpler (as does not have a shell kicking around)